# Personal information missing next to the picture

Tags: titles, moderncv

I am writing my CV and I can't understand what's wrong with my code but it doesn't work.

I'd like to have my name on the left, my picture on the right and the information just next to the picture but I can't display the personal information in any way.

Here what I wrote:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans,english]{moderncv}        
\moderncvstyle[left]{casual}
\moderncvcolor{black}
%\nopagenumbers{}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[scale=0.75,a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{babel}
\firstname{AAA}
\familyname{BBB}
%\title{}                               
\address{CCC, DDD}{12345}{EEE}         
\mobile{+1 23456789}                          
\email{xxx@gmail.com}                                              
\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{picture}

\begin{document}
\makecvtitle
\section{Section1}
\end{document}
```

But this doesn't show anything next to the picture but just in the footer:

[image: example]

How shall I do to make something appear?

T

Comment: That would be perfect! But I can't make it work... I get an error like "File tikz.sty not found. Do you know how can I solve this problem?

Comment: MikTeX. I am currently in the Package Manager and I see something like 15 different tikz packages. Which one shall I install?

Comment: Thank you very much! I solved the problem!! :) I'll vote your other answer!